# Building @mentions with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/sCDZR8P2hMrB33Ik5FNW

I'm trying to build a very basic @mentions functionality in Angular, but having a bit of trouble with the basics.

The link at the top shows what I have so far. What I'd like to do is, of course have the typeahead, pull the users from the $scope.competitionDetails.users and then perhaps if a match is found even linkify it.

Any guidance on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject [angular ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

This is a working example based on your code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oWZw5VrHGtwOGtuuh3yA?p=preview

Of course you need to change the address generation logic links (in the example only id is added to the current URL).

Comment: '@mentions functionality' implies that you have a trigger character, like '@', which triggers the popup which shows suggested matches.  I don't see that in this example and I don't think angular ui can do it.  @ruffrey's answer includes the trigger character.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using the library [mentio](https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io). Once you have mentio included, it goes something like this (using the built-in configurations):

JS:

```
var m = angular.module('m', ['mentio']);

m.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
      {label: 'asdf'},
      {label: 'bksdkf'},
      {label: 'ccc'}
  ];
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="m" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <textarea mentio
    mentio-typed-text="typedTerm"
    mentio-items="items | filter:label:typedTerm"
    ng-model="theTextArea2"
    autocomplete="off"></textarea>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77906ujr/